# Странное поведение объектов созданных методом new

Tags: javascript, классы, объекты

При создании объекта из конструктора в `Google Chrome` и выведении имени переменной, в которую сохранен объект, перед фигурными скобками стоит идентификатор конструктора, то есть в консоли выводиться `MyConstructor {...}`. Что это значит? Как я знаю в переменной должен содержаться адрес объекта, но откуда взялось названия конструктора перед фигурными скобками, то есть объектом?? При выполнении кода в других браузерах или тут такого нет...

```js
function MyConstructor() {};
    var a = new MyConstructor();
    console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Это просто отладочная информация, ссылка на конструктор доступна в прототипе

```js
function MyConstructor() {};
var a = new MyConstructor();
console.log(a.__proto__.constructor);
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все понял)

Answer (score 1):

Обратившись к спецификации [`console.log`](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#log), можно отметить, что указано выполнение [`Logger`](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#logger), с параметром `logLevel` = "log".

Пройдя дальше доходим до выполнения [`Printer`](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#printer), в котором отмечено, что данная операция *зависит от реализации*.

Это означает, что каждый браузер реализует ее так, как ему хочется:

Chrome, например, в зависимости от своих внутренних условий может выводить значение конструктора, либо *внутреннего поля [[ToStringTag]]*, либо ничего не выводить

EDGE, например, выводит строку полученную применением `toString` из `Object.prototype` к переданному объекту.